# SQL - See whether a manager is reporting to an employee he is managing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has a list of user ids and manager ids.
The table shows all employees and their managers - the managers also appear in the 'user id' section and their managers then show in the managers field.

Data example as it should below:

| User IDs | Manager Ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 12 |
| 9 | 13 |
| 12 | 8 |

What i want to find from my analysis is to see a count where user 1 who reports to manager 5 is also showing as the other way (is manager 5 reporting to manager 1).

So when i run the sql for the above analysis i should get back a count of 1 record with that anomoly ( user 8 is reporting to manager 12 and the other way round aswell)

Hope that makes sense. I am using Oracle 12g.

Comment: Manager id 13 is not in the user list, so your first paragraph is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no other duplicates and no `null` values (as in your sample data), you can use aggregation:

```
select least(user_id, manager_id), greatest(user_id, manager_id)
from t
group by least(user_id, manager_id), greatest(user_id, manager_id)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `exists` for this purpose.

```
 create table managers(User_IDs int,Manager_Ids int);

 insert into managers values (1,    5);
 insert into managers values (2,    1);
 insert into managers values (3,    7);
 insert into managers values (4,    2);
 insert into managers values (5,    9);
 insert into managers values (6,    3);
 insert into managers values (7,    5);
 insert into managers values (8,    12);
 insert into managers values (9,    13);
 insert into managers values (12, 8);
```

Query:

```
 select user_ids, Manager_Ids from managers a
 where exists
             (
                select 1 from managers b where a.user_Ids=b.Manager_Ids and a.Manager_Ids=b.user_Ids
             )
```

Output:

| USER_IDS | MANAGER_IDS |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 8 |
| 8 | 12 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=598ff65553cd1ce10b652fe718afa8cf)*